# A way to delete and recopy a .dll for each re-compile?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015, command-line-arguments

Basically, I have two projects, one which compiles to a dll and the other which consumes that dll. Right now I have a pre-build script which copies the dll into the dependent projects binary folder for use:

```
copy "$(SolutionDir)\DLLProj\Binaries\$(PlatformName)_$(Configuration)\DLLProj.dll" "$(SolutionDir)\DependentProj\Binaries\$(PlatformName)_$(Configuration)\"
```

This script seems to copy the dll upon first build but then on subsequent build and runs it is not being updated. At first I thought this was because my dll was not being rebuilt but I dont think this is the case. The only thing I can think of is that maybe my copy command is only running when there isn't a dll file found in my dependent project's folder? So the old dll just sits in there unless I clean or rebuild my project and then a new dll is copied to that location. If this is the case is there a command to make sure to delete or remove the dll from my dependent project upon exit? or any other way to ensure proper dll's on subsequent builds?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Try modify your copy command(make sure replace the existing file using `echo y|copy`):

```
echo y|copy "$(SolutionDir)\DLLProj\Binaries\$(PlatformName)_$(Configuration)\DLLProj.dll" "$(SolutionDir)\DependentProj\Binaries\$(PlatformName)_$(Configuration)\"
```

And **make sure** the `copy command` runs **after** you have built your `DllProject`.

**Another solution:**

I prefer using `.bat` instead:

1.`delete` old version of `.dll` file:

```
echo y|del "$(SolutionDir)\DependentProj\Binaries\$(PlatformName)_$(Configuration)\DLLProj.dll"
```

2.`copy` updated version

```
copy "$(SolutionDir)\DLLProj\Binaries\$(PlatformName)_$(Configuration)\DLLProj.dll" "$(SolutionDir)\DependentProj\Binaries\$(PlatformName)_$(Configuration)\"
```

As a result, your `.bat` file should be look like:

```
echo y|del "$(SolutionDir)\DependentProj\Binaries\$(PlatformName)_$(Configuration)\DLLProj.dll"

copy "$(SolutionDir)\DLLProj\Binaries\$(PlatformName)_$(Configuration)\DLLProj.dll" "$(SolutionDir)\DependentProj\Binaries\$(PlatformName)_$(Configuration)\"
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution is `xcopy /d`. This flag tells xcopy to only copy your DLL if the destination is outdated or missing.